# How to support the Use of self and Self within a Protocol?

Tags: swift, swiftui, types, functional-programming, protocols

**Context**

I am currently working with `Protocols` and encountered a problem. My `Protocol` has a `Static Type` and I would like to access it from an `Instance` of a `Struct` conforming to this `Protocol`. However, this results in the following `Compiler Error`:

> **Compiler Error:** Value of type 'any Component' has no member 'Self'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component {
    static var name: String { get set }
}

struct ComponentA: Component { static var name: String = "Component A" }
struct ComponentB: Component { static var name: String = "Component B" }

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(component.Self.name) // Compiler Error (see Context)
    }

    private var component: any Component {
        // Returns any component (ComponentA or ComponentB).
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I access the `Type` of the `Instance` conforming to the `Protocol`, e.g. `ComponentA` or `ComponentB` with the `Self Syntax`?

> **Note:** I also tried `type(of: component).name` which works. However, I am wondering why the `Self Syntax` is giving me a `Compiler Error`.

Comment: The compiler already told you why the "Self syntax" is giving you an error. "Value of type 'any Component' has no member 'Self'" How about just follow the design of Swift and use what works?

Comment: @Sweeper I still wanted to understand this.
Is there a possibility to add support for Self to the protocol?

Comment: Well, you can add a computed property called `Self` that just returns `type(of: self)` in an extension, but that seems rather pointless to me. Why not just do `type(of: component).name`. It's not *that* much more typing, is it?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for your help. Feel free to post it as an answer, so that I can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `component.Self` doesn't work is because `Self` is a type, and you are using it like a member of `component`. `component.Self` doesn't make sense for the same reason that `1.Int`, or `"foo".String` doesn't make sense. `component` doesn't have a member called `Self`.

You can, however, add a member called `Self` to `Component` using an extension:

```
extension Component {
    var Self: Self.Type { type(of: self) }
}
```

Now your `component.Self.name` would work.

But I don't quite see much point in doing this, when just writing `type(of: component).name` works as well.

Side note: unlike `component.Self` that doesn't make sense, `type(of: component)` is an *expression* (a function call to be specific) of type `any Component.Type`. This is what allows you to access `name`, because `any Component.Type` *does* have a member called `name`.

See also: [Self Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID610) in the Swift Language Reference